# Building custom web control, How to check if resource file already added?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building custom web control and I'm using js and css with it.
Js and Css files are embedded in control's dll.
The problem is when I'm adding this control to page more than one time the resources (js and css file) added again, is there a way to check if those files already added ?

Notice that this control can be added to any other container control (like div):
divId.Controls.Add(myCustomControl);
So I need a way to search for an ID in all sub controls in page

Thanx.

**UPDATE1:**
I'm usng this to add js files to container:

```
var plh = new PlaceHolder();
var js = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
jsID = "stacks";
js.Attributes.Add("src", Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(MyControlClass), "MyControlCSFileName.ScriptFolder.stacks.js"));
js.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
js.EnableViewState = false;
plh.Controls.Add(js);
plh.RenderControl(writer);
```

**UPDATE2:**
Some times I render control on server and return html result of it using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Use Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude to register your JS

Example:
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("key", Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "yourscript.js"));

Answer (score 0):

Use `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`

Refer: [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx)

> A client script is uniquely identified by its key and its type.
>   Scripts with the same key and type are considered duplicates. Only one
>   script with a given type and key pair can be registered with the page.
>   Attempting to register a script that is already registered does not
>   create a duplicate of the script.

You don't need to check duplicates, as asp.net will add only one instance.

However if you want to save the checking time, it does provide a function to check if a script is already registered: `IsClientScriptBlockRegistered`.

Comment: Some times I render the control on server and return the html result using Ajax. This wouldn't work in this case right ?

Comment: No, these blocks are not processed on partial postbacks.